# Postgresql Returned Nothing

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this SQL query:

```sql
select task_id, count(status) as not_paided 
        from some_table
        where status = 'not_paid' and task_id = 34
        group by task_id
```

If there are no `not_paid` rows, it should return 34/0 (`task_id`/`not_paided`), but it returns nothing. I have no idea what to do, already tried `case` and `coalesce`.

Comment: can you paste data from your some_table?

Comment: Since you already know from your query that the task_id is 34, can you not just use `SELECT count(status) not_paided from some_table where status = 'not_paid' and task_id = 34`?

Comment: Your second column is "paid" or "error".
Your WHERE-Clause should be `where status != 'paid'` 
or `where status not in ( 'paid' )`

Comment: I forgot to write, that i already tried this, @Hockenberry, but this does not work.

Comment: @iavery, 34 is for example, it may be 35 or 66, but only 34 task has no 'not_paid' statuses, and that's why I get wrong result.

Comment: @SMA data is simple 1st column - task_id's, 2nd - statuses (error,paid, not_paid)

Comment: The result 34/0 isn't working. If there are zero rows, the result is nothing.
The only possible solution is a sub query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 34/0 isn't possibile because there are zero rows with this where-clause.
If you really need it, you need a subquery. Somthine like this:

```
select 
    main.task_id, 
    (select count(sub.status) 
     from some_table as sub 
     where sub.status = 'not_paid' 
     and sub.tast_id = main.task_id) as not_paided
from some_table as main
where main.task_id = 34
```

EDIT:

Another way would be a `case when` with a simple `sum`

```
select 
    task_id, 
    sum(case when status = 'not_paid' then 1 else 0 end) as not_paided
from some_table
where task_id = 34
group by task_id
```